# ResourceAwareScheduler is not found in Storm 2.1.0

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

I am using Storm 2.1.0 and would like to use the [Resource Aware Scheduler](https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.1.0/Resource_Aware_Scheduler_overview.html). I followed instructions from the documentation and added the following line to my *conf/storm.yaml*:

```
storm.scheduler: “org.apache.storm.scheduler.resource.ResourceAwareScheduler”
```

But when I execute `./bin/storm nimbus` it crashes and I can see the following log in *logs/nimbus.log*:

```
2020-06-25 16:02:09.962 o.a.s.d.n.Nimbus main [INFO] Using custom scheduler: “org.apache.storm.scheduler.resource.ResourceAwareScheduler”
2020-06-25 16:02:09.963 o.a.s.u.Utils main [ERROR] Received error in thread main.. terminating server...
java.lang.Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: “org.apache.storm.scheduler.resource.ResourceAwareScheduler”
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.handleUncaughtException(Utils.java:653) ~[storm-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.handleUncaughtException(Utils.java:632) ~[storm-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.lambda$createDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler$2(Utils.java:1014) ~[storm-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1057) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1052) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1959) [?:1.8.0_252]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: “org.apache.storm.scheduler.resource.ResourceAwareScheduler”
    at org.apache.storm.utils.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:48) ~[storm-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.makeScheduler(Nimbus.java:658) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.<init>(Nimbus.java:569) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.<init>(Nimbus.java:474) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.<init>(Nimbus.java:468) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.launchServer(Nimbus.java:1307) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.launch(Nimbus.java:1332) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.main(Nimbus.java:1337) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: “org.apache.storm.scheduler.resource.ResourceAwareScheduler”
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:46) ~[storm-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.makeScheduler(Nimbus.java:658) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.<init>(Nimbus.java:569) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.<init>(Nimbus.java:474) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.<init>(Nimbus.java:468) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.launchServer(Nimbus.java:1307) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.launch(Nimbus.java:1332) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.main(Nimbus.java:1337) ~[storm-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
```

I understand that the class is not found but wasn't expecting this. I just downloaded the latest version of Storm from their official website (binary version), I checked on the source code if the class exists (it does), Zookeeper is up and running, and I followed the given instruction to enable this scheduler. I probably forgot something but I totally don't know what.

But anyway, let's continue this investigation. In *Nimbus.java* it initializes the scheduler:

```
private static IScheduler makeScheduler(Map<String, Object> conf, INimbus inimbus) {
    String schedClass = (String) conf.get(DaemonConfig.STORM_SCHEDULER);
    IScheduler scheduler = inimbus == null ? null : inimbus.getForcedScheduler();
    if (scheduler != null) {
        LOG.info("Using forced scheduler from INimbus {} {}", scheduler.getClass(), scheduler);
    } else if (schedClass != null) {
        LOG.info("Using custom scheduler: {}", schedClass);
        scheduler = ReflectionUtils.newInstance(schedClass);
    } else {
        LOG.info("Using default scheduler");
        scheduler = new DefaultScheduler();
    }
    return scheduler;
}
```

The following log tells me that it's trying to get the correct scheduler:

```
... Nimbus main [INFO] Using custom scheduler: “org.apache.storm.scheduler.resource.ResourceAwareScheduler”
```

An then, it calls `ReflectionUtils.newInstance()` which is implemented in *ReflectionUtils.java*:

```
public static <T> T newInstance(String klass) {
    try {
        return newInstance((Class<T>) Class.forName(klass));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Exception seems to be raised from here because it is not able to find the class `ResourceAwareScheduler`. I double checked and the class exist at the given location. At this stage I got to admit that it reaches my knowledge of Java. Am I suppose to manually import this class in *ReflectionUtils.java*? It has the full path to the class, so I suppose it is not necessary. How should I configure this Maven project to include this class?

Any help with this will be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem. There is a difference between:

```
storm.scheduler: “org.apache.storm.scheduler.resource.ResourceAwareScheduler”
```

and

```
storm.scheduler: "org.apache.storm.scheduler.resource.ResourceAwareScheduler"
```

Even the highlighting for code from StackOverflow should have helped me. I feel stupid. It's a gentle reminder that copy-pasting, even from official documentation, is bad! Hope this will help other bros.